# Return array indices from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, indexing

I have an array and function and I would like the function to return a list of indices in which the difference of two consecutive elements passes a threshold.

I have:

```
def func (y, t=100):
    for i in range(1, len(y)): #Range skips 1st element
        if abs(y[i] - y[i-1]) > t:
            return(i)
```

The problem I'm facing is that this function only returns the first index where my if statement is true. How do I get the rest of them?

Comment: `yield i` and collect  items in a `list`(In other words convert your function to a generator function)

Comment: Don't return it. Just capture it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways. First, `yield` instead of `return` will give you a generator:

```
def func (y, t=100):
    for i in range(1, len(y)): #Range skips 1st element
        if abs(y[i] - y[i-1]) > t:
            yield(i)
```

Or add a list in you function:

```
def func (y, t=100):
    output = []
    for i in range(1, len(y)): #Range skips 1st element
        if abs(y[i] - y[i-1]) > t:
            output.append(i)
    return output
```

Answer (score 4):

With a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you can do that like:

#### Code:

```
def peak_detect(in_data, threshold=100):
    return [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(in_data, in_data[1:]))
            if abs(y - x) >= threshold]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [1, 2000, 2001, 4000]

print(peak_detect(data))
```

#### Result:

```
[0, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def peak_detect (y_, threshold=100):
    indicesList = []
    for i in range(1, len(y_)): #Range skips 1st element
        if abs(y[i] - y[i-1]) > threshold:
            indicesList.append(i)
    return(indicesList)
```